# Turn on wiremock logs

Tags: java, logback, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I can't get any wiremock logs in the console during the execution tests

java - wiremock - testNG

wiremock standalone starts on pod using java with option **--verbose**
also, set **level="TRACE"** for **STDOUT** in **logback.xml** file

however, I added different settings WireMockRule in test, ex.

```
new WireMockRule(new WireMockConfiguration()
                .notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true))
                .extensions(new ResponseTemplateTransformer(true)));
```

If you have any thoughts or suggestions how to turn on the wiremock logs please help me. By the way, I see the wiremock logs in pod but I'd like that it displayed in my console

```
2021-12-15 18:36:35.939 Warning: failed to parse the XML document
XML: null
2021-12-15 18:36:40.939 Admin request received: 0.2.1 - GET /mappings
```